# How can I get better error information with try/except in Python

Tags: python, error-handling

Consider this `try`/`except` block I use for checking error message stored in `e`.

#### Try/Catch to get the `e`

```
queryString = "SELECT * FROM benchmark WHERE NOC = 2"
try:
    res = db.query(queryString) 
except SQLiteError, e:
    # `e` has the error info 
    print `e`
```

The `e` object here contains nothing more than the above string. When python reports an unhandled error, however, it shows a pretty detailed info as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fool.py", line 1, in 
    open("abc.zyz", "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.zyz'
```

My question is, how can I get the information such as above (the file and the line number etc.)? Or, if `e` contains this info, how is it stored inside it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will show the trace to the error.

```
import traceback

try:
    res = db.query(queryString) 
except SQLiteError, e:
    # `e` has the error info 
    print `e`
    for tb in traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2]):
        print tb
```

Answer (score 3):

Like the first 2 answers, use `traceback`. Here is a more complete example.

```
import traceback

def foo():
    raise RuntimeError('we have a problem')

try:
    foo()
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

When you run it, you'll see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\0\tmp\x.py", line 6, in <module>
    foo()
  File "C:\0\tmp\x.py", line 3, in foo
    raise RuntimeError('we have a problem')
RuntimeError: we have a problem
```

Answer (score 2):

1. See the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) library.
2. If you want to just pass errors up the chain instead of modifying them, you can just use `raise` within an `except` block, which will then act like the `except` block isn't there (aside from any conditional logic/side effects you may have done before the `raise`).