# C# equivalent to Python's traceback library

Tags: c#, python, exception, error-handling

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697452/how-can-i-get-better-error-information-with-try-catch-in-python/3698101#3698101), python has traceback library to get some detailed error information (line number, file name ...).

Does C# have similar functions to know what file/line number that generates the exception?

### ADDED

I came up with the following code based on the answers.

```
using System;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474259/c-exception-handling-with-a-string-given-to-a-constructor

class WeekdayException : Exception {
    public WeekdayException(String wday) : base("Illegal weekday: " + wday) {}
}

class TryCatchFinally 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        try
        {
            throw new WeekdayException("thrown by try");
        }
        catch(WeekdayException weekdayException) {
            Console.WriteLine(weekdayException.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(weekdayException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives me this message:

```
Illegal weekday: thrown by try
  at TryCatchFinally.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: The way the title is written, it sounds like you're looking for the equivalent of C#'s library in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you catch an exception you can view its stack trace, which should give similar results:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

If debug data can be loaded (if the .pdb file is in the same directory as the executable/you build in debug mode) this will include file names line numbers.  If not it will only include method names.

Comment: Yes, I could get the line number with csc, but not with mono. I posted another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474547/monos-mdb-file-vs-cscs-pdb-file

Comment: @prosseek: Unfortunately I don't know much about mono, hopefully someone else will have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception gets thrown, check out the stack trace - it will give you the same results.

Answer (score 1):

All classes that inherit from `Exception` have a [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property.  It's not quite the same as the Python `traceback` library because of the nature of how C#/.NET is run (like it won't have an equivalent to `tb_lineno`).  All it is is the string representation of the stack trace.